# The required field 'image_url' was not supplied

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using big commerce API v3 https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/xxxxxxxxxx/v3/ (catalog/products) to create a new product.

I want to pull this image from `WEBDAV` and I have uploaded this product as `product_images/import/product-1.jpg` in `WEBDAV`.

The input data is in POST like,

```
{
    "categories": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "name": "My Product",
    "sku": "MP1",
    "type": "physical",
    "depth": 0,
    "price": 5,
    "sale_price": 3,
    "images": [
        {
            "image_file": "product-1.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "description": "My first product description"
},
```

but it is returned `400: The required field 'image_url' was not supplied.`

It is working with full URL using `image_url` but not working with `image_file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. The docs are going to be updated to clearly display the expected behavior and use of this endpoint.

The endpoint requires the "image_url" path, which you do not have by only uploading the file with webdav. So, after you upload the image to webdav, you will have to add the store url prior to the image path. Like "image_url": "https://store-domain.com/product-1.jpg"